# Automate a Mount of a Remote Directory in Bash Using sshfs and expect

Tags: bash, expect, sshfs

I am able to mount a remote SFTP directory using the root user, however when I try to run a bash script to automate the same, the script runs with no errors, however the mount is never created.

I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash

_SSHHOST="sub.domain.com"
_SSHUSER="10001"
_SSHPASS="somepass"
_DATADIR="/mnt/data"

# Create user if doesn't exist
id -u $_SSHUSER &>/dev/null || useradd $_SSHUSER 
# Create directory if doesn't exist
mkdir -p $_DATADIR/$_SSHUSER
# Change ownership of dir to new user
chown $_SSHUSER:root $_DATADIR/$_SSHUSER

/usr/bin/expect <<EOD

spawn sshfs $_SSHUSER@$_SSHHOST:/remote/dir $_DATADIR/$_SSHUSER
expect "Password: "
send "$_SSHPASS\r"
expect "#"

EOD
```

No mount is created and there are no files listed in the created directory. I appreciate that some people will say to avoid using Bash and create this directly in Expect, however this is just a very small portion of a larger script that performs numerous bash functions. What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
I fixed this by passing `-o password_stdin` into the `sshfs` command. Thanks everyone for looking.

Answer (score 2):

So I think the problem you're running into is expect only works on the output from the program you're using it on

In this case sshfs prompts for:

```
$_SSHUSER@$_SSHHOST's password:
```

Once you normally would type in the password it would fork into the background and there would not be a # to expect to get.

What I think you're seeing is the # on the next line of your terminal after the sshfs tool forks so you can't expect that

As an alternative to an expect script sshfs accepts the password via stdin with

```
echo $_SSHPASS | sshfs -o password_stdin $_SSHUSER@$_SSHHOST:/remote/dir $_DATADIR/$_SSHUSER
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by passing the `-o password_stdin` flag into the `sshfs` command. Thanks everyone for looking.